# What is the policy regarding flags on comments in chat rooms?

Tags: support, chat, flagging

Each comment in [The Base Camp](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp) chat room has a flag beside it.

Hovering over it says "flag this message as spam, inappropriate or offensive."

I have a few questions about that flag and its implications.

- If it's selected, is there another step? For instance, does it offer a choice of reason before reporting it? Is there a message asking to confirm that you want to flag it? One reason I'm asking that is because many times I've almost flagged a post by accident because the flag is so close to the star. If I had hit a flag, and another choice came up, I could have changed my mind before anyone knew I did it!
- Does it go into a queue to be reviewed by the moderators? If so, how many moderator votes are necessary to make a determination?
- Does the person who flagged it get any notification as to the outcome?
- If someone receives a certain number of flagged comments, are they penalized? If so, what's the penalty?
- If someone raises a certain number of flags that the moderators feel are unjustified, are they penalized? If so, what's the penalty?
- If someone feels their comments have been unfairly flagged, what course of action should they take?

Comment: Related: [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271268/241919)

Comment: @Sue - that link Andrew posted is literally everything you could ever want to know about chat flags :-)

Comment: @AndrewT., thanks for that long and informative list!!! As Rory Alsop said, that's what I wanted to know and much more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the meta guide: [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat) is very good. One thing it does not touched on, nor does your question, is *who should flag*. In my experience, each chat room has its own style. While the general terms of the CoC need to be upheld, there is a fair amount of leeway. For example, some chat rooms allow off topic discussions others don't; some allow profanity and others don't.

If you enter a chat room for the first time and see colorful language, you may not want to immediately start flagging everything. If a new user comes into a room you are a regular in and starts cussing like a sailor, you may want to tell the user to tone it down and flag the content. In general, if you are finding lots of stuff to flag by a lot of users, it may not be the right chat room for you. If there is a single problematic user, you should definitely flag away. If an otherwise well behaved user says something bad, flag it (or tell the user how you feel).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is they don't. They show up void of context and really are less than useful.

With that said I have raised flags in chat 3 times as compared to almost 1.5k on the main site,

- Someone's CAPS LOCK key got jammed
- Someone asked to delete spam in such a way that the spam link was still visible (not actually a problem just need a mod to edit)
- Someone else asked about a specific spam website and left the link visible in chat. (not actually a problem just need a mod to edit)

This normally isn't a problem here.

For an example of why they don't have context see this picture of what the interface looks like,

[image]

[How users flag in chat or react to flags is totally broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374239/how-users-flag-in-chat-or-react-to-flags-is-totally-broken)

And just to prove I am not the only one [Flags in chat are defective by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203346/flags-in-chat-are-defective-by-design)

Comment: @Sue As a 10k user, I have reviewed a number of chat flags and they don't come with context at all. Its a highly frustrating experience that so far **you don't have**

Comment: @Sue https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374239/how-users-flag-in-chat-or-react-to-flags-is-totally-broken